# Get row count before group by

Tags: mysql

I have a 'votes' table with this structure:

```
-------------------
id | video | rate |
-------------------
0  | 1     | 8    |
-------------------
1  | 1     | 9    |
-------------------
2  | 2     | 6    |
-------------------
3  | 3     | 4    |
-------------------
```

I want to calculate the Bayesian average for each video.
In order to achieve this, I need access to some variables, like the whole table's average number of votes, average rating of all movies etc.

I am using the following query to group videos:

```sql
SELECT video,
    SUM(rate),
    COUNT(*) AS "# votes"
    # I need the total number of rows here, before grouping is applied
FROM votes
GROUP BY video
```

I can't find a way to get values of the whole table, before the videos are grouped. I tried the WITH clause to create a temporary table to store these whole table aggregates, but I am getting a 'unrecognized statement' for WITH (on both phpmyadmin and MySQL Workbench). I checked that the mysql version is 14.14.

EDIT:
The answer @nbk gave solves my problem, but is there a clearer way to access these values? The Bayes formula expects a considerable amount of repeated variables, and the query ends up complicated:

```sql
SELECT video,
    SUM(rate) AS rates_sum,
    COUNT(*) AS 'votes', # v
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes) AS total_votes,
    ROUND(AVG(rate), 1) AS 'movie_average', # A
    # (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes) ... AS 'average num of votes of all videos' # v_avg
    (SELECT SUM(rate) FROM votes) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes) AS 'average rating of all videos' # S
    # (v / (v + v_avg)) * A + (v_avg / (v + v_avg)) * S AS score <--- Bayes average formula
FROM votes
GROUP BY video;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a column with the `SELeCT COUNT(*)`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE votes (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `video` INTEGER,
>   `rate` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO votes
>   (`id`, `video`, `rate`)
> VALUES
>   ('0', '1', '8'),
>   ('1', '1', '9'),
>   ('2', '2', '6'),
>   ('3', '3', '4');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT video,
>     SUM(rate),
>     COUNT(*) AS "# votes",
>     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes) Total_votes
> FROM votes
> GROUP BY video
> ```
>
> ```
> video | SUM(rate) | # votes | Total_votes
> ----: | --------: | ------: | ----------:
>     1 |        17 |       2 |           4
>     2 |         6 |       1 |           4
>     3 |         4 |       1 |           4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aee501340813b8fa4624dbbb95635aa7)*